# Is there a way for Visual Basic to know if a 3rd party program is minimized?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a program in excel Visual Basic to communicate with a, rather archaic program, in which my company stores all of its sales information.

I am hoping to get a way to allow my excel program to know when the 3rd party program is done with it's task.

I have created a macro within the other program, which ends with minimizing the program, and I am wondering if VBA can know that the window of the other program is minimized or not.

Comment: Why minimise the program?  Can, for example, the archaic program create a dummy file when it has finished?  The existence of this file would be much easier to detect.

Comment: Oh my, that is brilliant.

Comment: I believe that it is indeed able to do that, thank you

Comment: I would like to claim brilliant but old would be more accurate.  Creating a dummy file to indicate a process had finished was a common technique when I was young.

Answer (score 2):

Although I realize you found a work-around in the comments, I thought I'd post a solution for anyone else that finds this question.  You can use an API call to [IsIconic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to test whether a window is minimized:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function IsIconic Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean

Public Sub Example()

    Shell "notepad.exe", vbMinimizedNoFocus

    Dim hwnd As Long
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Untitled - Notepad")
    Debug.Print IsIconic(hwnd)

End Sub
```